# How to Link to a function from a DLL loaded by a DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-c++-6

I'm using VS2010 and I have a layered application that looks like this:

```
app.exe
DLL1.dll
DLL2.dll
```

where app.exe loads DLL1 and it then loads DLL2. I want my app to call a function in DLL2 like so `DLL2::setvariable( value )`.

I've set this up properly in my vc6 workspace without having to specify the lib file for `DLL2.dll`. How can I set this up in my VS2010 environment? I keep getting an unresolved symbol linker error for all the calls to `DLL2.dll`.

I've tried to include 
`#pragma comment(lib ,"DLL2.lib")` 
in both `app.exe` and `DLL1.dll` and it links but does this load `DLL2.dll` and all its variables twice?

Comment: _"...but does this load DLL2.dll and all its variables twice?"_ No

Comment: Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: The linker cannot possibly link against a DLL without an import library. It doesn't matter whether you are using a tool that's 2 decades old, or a recent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DLL is only loaded once in an application's address-space. This is by Windows design. An import-library for a dll loads the dll (`LoadLibrary()`) and assigns local function names to the dll functions. You could do the same yourself by calling `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`.

According to the [**Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)**:**

*The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).*

So no, a DLL is only loaded once, only its "UseCount" is set to 2.

> I've set this up properly in my vc6 workspace without having to specify the lib file for DLL2.dll

I guess you weren't calling `DLL2::setvariable( value )` from `app.exe` then, otherwise how did you do it?

> Is this the right way to do it?

This is one way to do it (though you could simply include the `lib` into the project - as most developers do - instead of using the `#pragma`, but the rseult is the same). The other alternative is call `LoadLibrary()`/`GetProcAddress()` yourself (useful if you want to conditionally load the dll). There's no other way i'm aware of.

Comment: I was calling DLL2.dll from my app.exe in the vc6 project. I think the there is an implicit setting that links the DLL at compile-time. I'm new to VC6.

Comment: Yes, the **import library** (not the DLL, this is loaded/linked dynamically at run-time), must have been somehow included into the project (maybe through that `#pragma` in an include file?), otherwise you would be getting link errors, this is what I meant.